# Show that $n\mathbb{Z} + m\mathbb{Z} = h \mathbb{Z}$, where $h = hcf(m,n)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

As the question says. I'm having trouble putting all the pieces together. I've shown that $m$ divides $n$ if and only if $n \Bbb Z$ is a subring of $m \Bbb Z$ and vice versa. does this suffice to show that $n \Bbb Z + m \Bbb Z = d \Bbb Z$ where d is some divisor of $m$ and $n$, and then show that $d$ must be the greatest common divisor? I'm struggling to see what exactly I need to prove/how to put them together.

Comment: A hint that might get you on the right track: You need to prove that $h\mathbb{Z} \subseteq n\mathbb{Z} + m\mathbb{Z}$, and also that $n\mathbb{Z} + m\mathbb{Z} \subseteq h\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @AlexZorn thank you, this was my initial thought. I argued that m (respectively n) is divisible by h so any multiple of m (resp. n) is also a multiple of h., so $m\mathbb{Z}$ (resp. $n\mathbb{Z}$) is in $h\mathbb{Z}$. Since $h\mathbb{Z}$ is closed under addition this seems to imply $m\mathbb{Z} + n\mathbb{Z}$ is also in $h\mathbb{Z}$. I'm having trouble proving the reverse however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, every ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$ is of the form $a\mathbb{Z}$, for a unique integer $a\ge0$, so $n\mathbb{Z}+m\mathbb{Z}=h\mathbb{Z}$, for a unique $h\ge0$. However, we can dismiss the case $h=0$ as very easy: if $h=0$, then also $n=m=0$.

You want to show that $h$ is the greatest common divisor (highest common factor) of $n$ and $m$.

Let's prove that $h$ divides both $n$ and $m$. Indeed, $n=n1+m0\in n\mathbb{Z}+m\mathbb{Z}=h\mathbb{Z}$, so $n=hr$, for some integer $r$. Similarly, $h$ divides $m$.

Note also that $h=na+mb$, for some integers $a$ and $b$, by definition of $n\mathbb{Z}+m\mathbb{Z}$. Suppose $k$ is a (positive) common divisor of $n$ and $m$, so $n=kr$ and $m=ks$. Then
$$
h=na+mb=kra+ksb=k(ra+sb)
$$
proves that $k$ is a divisor of $h$, hence $k\le h$.

Answer (score 0):

**Easy direction.**

We'll show that $n\mathbb{Z}+m\mathbb{Z} \subseteq \mathrm{hcf}(n,m)\mathbb{Z}$. Since $\mathrm{hcf}(n,m) \mid n,$ hence $$n\mathbb{Z} \subseteq \mathrm{hcf}(n,m)\mathbb{Z}.$$ Similarly $$m\mathbb{Z} \subseteq \mathrm{hcf}(n,m)\mathbb{Z}.$$ So $$n\mathbb{Z}+m\mathbb{Z} \subseteq \mathrm{hcf}(n,m)\mathbb{Z}.$$

(Try to justify all the steps above in your own writeup by formulating them as Lemmas and then proving the Lemmas.)

**Hard direction.**

We need to show that $\mathrm{hcf}(n,m)\mathbb{Z} \subseteq n\mathbb{Z}+m\mathbb{Z}$.

It suffices to show that $\mathrm{hcf}(n,m) \in n\mathbb{Z}+m\mathbb{Z}$.

(Try to justify this in your own writeup by formulating it as a Lemma and proving it.)

But this is a consequence of Bezout's theorem.

Comment: Thank you, I just saw this after replying to the comment on the question. The reverse is definitely trickier.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x\in h\mathbb Z$.  There exist integers $a$ and $b$ with $ma+nb=h$ (Euclidean algorithm).   Now $x=hz$, for $z\in \mathbb Z$.  So $x=(ma+nb)z=maz+nbz$.  This shows $x\in m\mathbb Z+n\mathbb Z$.  Then $h\mathbb Z\subset m\mathbb Z+n\mathbb Z$.

Conversely let$x\in m\mathbb Z+n\mathbb Z$.  Then $x=mz_1+nz_2$.  But $h|m,n$.  Hence $x=hcz_1+hdz_2=h(cz_1+dz_2)$ for some $c,d,z_1,z_2\in \mathbb Z$...  Thus $x\in h\mathbb Z$.  Thus $m\mathbb Z+n\mathbb Z\subset h\mathbb Z$...

Answer (score 0):

This follows from a well known fact (using the Euclidean algorithm):

> Let $m,n\in\mathbb{Z}$ then there exists $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $$mx+ny=h$$ where $h=\gcd(m,n)$

It is enough to show that $$h\mathbb{Z}\subseteq m\mathbb{Z}+n\mathbb{Z}\subseteq h\mathbb{Z}$$

- Any element in $h\mathbb{Z}$ is a multiple of $h$, so it must be divisible by $mx+ny$. This means that $h\mathbb{Z}\subseteq m\mathbb{Z}+n\mathbb{Z}$
- Since $m\mathbb{Z}\subseteq h\mathbb{Z}$ and $n\mathbb{Z}\subseteq h\mathbb{Z}$ we must also have that $m\mathbb{Z}+n\mathbb{Z}\subseteq h\mathbb{Z}$

Therefore $$m\mathbb{Z}+n\mathbb{Z}=h\mathbb{Z}$$